# Php form submit doesnt respond

Tags: php

Here are two files. when i click on submit nothing happens. there is a print_r but it doesnt display anything. for the form action i left it empty because its on the same page. can someone help? thanks in advance.

## update_avatar.func.php

```
 <?php

  // la function  qui va changer l'image de profl du membre

function modifier_image_profile($avatar_tmp,$avatar)
{

move_uploaded_file($avatar_tmp,'avatar/'.$avatar);
mysql_query("UPDATE utilisateurs SET avatar='{$_FILES['avatar']['name']}'  WHERE pseudo= '{$_SESSION['pseudo']}'");


}


?>
```

================================================================

## update_avatar.php

```
 <?php

include ('functions/membre.func.php');
 include ('body/header.php');
include ('body/menu.php');

?>


<h3> Changer votre image de profil</h3>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$avatar=$_FILES['avatar']['name'];
$avatar_tmp=$_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
$avatar="profile.jpg";
if (!empty($avatar))
{
    $image_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$avatar)));
    print_r($image_ext); 
    if(in_array($image_ext,array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif')))
    {

        modifier_image_profile($avatar_tmp,$avatar);
        header("Location:index.php?page=membre");

    }else{
        echo "<div class='error'>Veuillez saisir une image valide</div>";


    }
}

}
foreach ($infos as $info)

{

?>
 <img src='avatar/<?php echo $info['avatar'];?>'height='100' width='100'  alt='avatar'
<?php


}


?>

<form method='POST' action ='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

<input type="file" name="avatar"><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Valider" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This code is incredibly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Furthermore, try setting the value of `action` in your html form to the current page instead of to something empty.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST)` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Should `include ('functions/membre.func.php');` be `include ('functions/update_avatar.func.php');`?

Comment: im still newbie...lol  what value please? --->//update_avatar.php// !?

Comment: @Barmar  it gives -->    array(0) { }

Comment: @thepieterdc  i tried --->  action ='index.php?page=update_avatar' result=nothing happens

Comment: @thepieterdc Leaving the action empty defaults to using the current page's URL, so it should work when you display and process the form in the same script.

Comment: @jojik Are other scripts able to process their form parameters?

Comment: @barmar ---->i dont know how to close the topic . the answer is that the tag img was not closed. thanks everybody

Comment: You can't delete it since an answer was posted. Use the `flag` link to ask the moderators to close it because of a typo.